# Posting a part of surveymonkey survey to other database

Tags: surveymonkey

I have a specific need regarding Surveymonkey engine. I would like to build a survey including a bunch of sensitive questions (address, telephone etc.). According to legal regulations we cannot store those datas in Surveymonkey database, but in a separate, certivied database of us own. So there's a question - is that possible to embed any kind of external form inside SM survey, that would post data to other database? Or to place inside SM survey a script (i.e. javascript), that would do that? Thank you for any kind of advice!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

Comment: Can you cite a reference to something that says this is so (including a link to the source of that reference)? If not, this is not an answer here.

Comment: O course, there's no problem. Dealing with sensitive data in Poland is regulated by Personal Data Protection Act from 1997. If you are really interested, you can find it here http://isip.sejm.gov.pl/DetailsServlet?id=WDU19971330883 (it's a website of Polish lawmaker). I am affraid no English version is available online, though. According to this act sensitive data can only be kept in  certified database at the risk of data's owner. Since we cannot provide to the regulator detailed information about the way SurveyMonkey protects it's customer's data, we have to use our own database.

Comment: Whoa, I just noticed, that I'm not the one that have been asked to explain why "it is so". Apologies for spamming you :)

Comment: @KenWhite There is only sporadic documentation on SurveyMonkey for features they don't support, and this is not documented.  SurveyMonkey does not currently have a callback mechanism to submit answers to another site/service and does not support ever not storing survey answers in their DB.  How would you recommend I can answer this in a satisfactory StackOverflow way?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, what you just wrote in your comment to me could be turned into an answer much better than the one I commented on. :-) "No, it's not" isn't the same as "No, it's not because...".

Comment: Cool, I'll be sure to add more detail next time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed an external form in an iframe. To do that you'll need to enable HTML as described in this article which describes the technique for embedding other media in a survey but which can be extrapolated to embedding forms: http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/How-do-I-add-a-video-or-sound-clip-to-my-survey

This article also covers adding a form in an iframe, but the content is specific to Wufoo forms: http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Can-I-include-a-form-in-my-survey-design

Comment: Please summarize the article that you linked, quoting any relevant code segments or configuration blocks.  Sites can change in the future or fail to load for any number of reasons.